# Is a way to generate random number using XSLT 1.0 [Teamsite CMS]

Tags: xslt, teamsite, interwoven

I'm trying to generate random number using **XSLT 1.0** (in Teamsite). Every time I generate a page a new random number should be generated as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359134/random-items-in-xslt

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867727/generate-random-number-in-rss-viewer-webpart/25869149#25869149

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2360489/36305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Teamsite XSLT uses xalan-j processor, it allows you to use Java library functions and below code will helps you creating random number everytime you generate a page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan math"
                  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                  xmlns:math="xalan://java.lang.Math">
       <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:value-of select="math:random()"/>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```